# get the Page's HiddenField Value in UserControl on Page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, hidden-field

I want to read the Page(.aspx) Hiddenfield Value in the User Control that is placed on that Page and process some logic.

FOr eg: I have a hidden field x on a Page. The Page has many user controls and I want to access this hidden field (x) in those User Controls where  value of x will be set by a Javascript in the Page.

I am trying to find the HiddenControl and read its value from codebehind of usercontrol(.ascx.cs) but always get null.

```
HiddenField colname = UIUtils.FindControlRecursive(this.Parent.Page, "MainContent_AssignedTo_ColName") as HiddenField;
```

The ID is same as the hiddenfield on client Side. I tried `this.Parent` and `this.Parent.Parent` for the first argument too but no luck.

what am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
HiddenField colname = (HiddenField)Page.FindControl("The id of control");
```

Comment: Is your control within a placeholder?

Comment: Yes, its inside a Content Placeholder and thats the reason we have got the MainContent_ appended to the ID of the Hiddenfield while finding it. And the UserControl is also in the Same Content PlaceHolder

Comment: Do you mean `(HiddenField)<IDof ContentPlaceHolder>.FindControl("The id of control");` I think it doesn't work. lemme know if I get you wrong.

Comment: I tested your scenario on my dev machine - and my original answer should work.

Comment: Okay, let me give you more details. There are many instances of this user control on the Page. lets say that user control is a grid. when a user updates a row, I am picking up the column name in this hidden field using Javascript and as you know rowUpdating event fires in the codebehind of this grid which is our user control. All I want is what column was edited in my row editing event. But the above code snippet returns NULL. Thats what surprising me and posted here to verify if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I tryed this and placed another answer below.  It works for me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestFindControl._Default" %>
<%@ Register Src="ReadHiddenField.ascx" TagName="Assign" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value="10">
    </asp:HiddenField>

<asp:placeholder ID="Placeholder1" runat="server"><uc1:Assign id="test" runat="server"></uc1:Assign> </asp:placeholder> 
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my code behind on control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HiddenField test = (HiddenField)Page.FindControl("HiddenField1");
            var j = test.Value;

        }
```

Comment: I've tried here too but no luck...I will post my Page Code shortly.

Comment: Its been awhile with me working with master pages - but here is something to try.  Try getting the content holder first using the same way I did in first answer- but cast its class.  Then substitute Page with the name you give the content  holder.  This may work.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void GetParentPageHiddenField()
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField ParenthiddenField = null;
        Control ctl = this.Parent;
        while (true)
        {
            ParenthiddenField = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField)ctl.FindControl("ParentPageHiddenFieldID");
            if (ParenthiddenField == null)
            {
                if (ctl.Parent == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                ctl = ctl.Parent;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        var parentHiddenFieldValue=ParenthiddenField.Value;
    }
```

Comment: In the UserControl Page